# How can I add integers in an array

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to add some number in an array.

Example:

```
array=( 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 )
```

I've done it this way but I want to use an array and then sum up the numbers in a shell script.

```
num1=2
num2=4
num3=8
num4=10
num5=12
num6=14
num7=16
num8=18
num9=20
sum=$((num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9))
echo "The sum is: $sum"
```

Comment: Are you fussy about the language of the shell script?  You've tagged the question with bash, but don't specify elsewhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do:

```
$ array=( 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)

$ echo "${array[@]/,/+}" | bc               
110
```

- `${array[@]/,/+}` is a parameter expansion pattern that replaces all `,` with `+` in all elements of the `array`
- Then `bc` simply does the addition

Let's break it up a bit for clarification:

```
$ array=( 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)

$ echo "${array[@]/,/+}"                     
2+ 4+ 6+ 8+ 10+ 12+ 14+ 16+ 18+ 20

$ echo "${array[@]/,/+}" | bc
110
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks to be what I'm looking for.  I did not know about bc. I will definitely keep this for future use.

Comment: No need for commas: `array=( 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20); echo "${array[@]/%/+}0" | bc`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson OP has literal commas in the array declaration..i have used it verbatim  :)

Comment: I don't think the OP was being literal.  All this does is lead to confusion about BASH array constructs.

Comment: @Progrock Quoting OP `I've done it this way but I want to use an array and then sum up the numbers` ..I think OP is clear over there..

Comment: Yes OP is clear in that they want to use an array, but obviously doesn't know how to.  Hence the question.

Comment: OP's original array was not properly declared.

Answer (score 4):

```
num1=2
num2=4
num3=8
array=($num1 $num2 $num3)
declare -i sum
IFS=+ sum="${array[*]}"
echo $sum
```

Output:

```
14
```

---

See: `help declare`

Comment: No need for `declare` or `IFS`: `array=(2 4 8); ((sum = ${array[@]/%/+}0)); echo "$sum"`

Answer (score 3):

Using a loop in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

nums=(1 2 3)
total=0
for n in ${nums[@]}
do
  (( total += n ))
done
echo $total
```

Outputs 6.

Comment: `(( total += n ))`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, I think that is a little less intuitive for beginners, but it's most likely more idiomatic and cleaner.  Thanks, I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Python it's very simple to add a list of numbers.

```
$ python -c 'print sum([1,2,3])'
```

Outputs 6.

Comment: not quite..the array elements contain literal `,`s..perhaps you can do `rstrip(',')` on all elements and then do the addition..anyway i think OP is meaning shell here, not a high level language  :)

Comment: It works as is.

Comment: It's also quite easy in Turbo Pascal.

Answer (score 1):

One could also use `awk` to perform the looping summation:

```
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
1 2 3
$ awk 'BEGIN{for (arg in ARGV) sum += arg;print sum}' "${arr[@]}"
6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=(1 2 3)
echo Sum of array elements: $(( ${arr[@]/%/ +} 0))
Sum of array elements: 6
```

Explanation:

1. `"${arr[@]/%/ +}"` will return `1 + 2 + 3 +`
2. By adding additional zero at the end we will get `1 + 2 + 3 + 0`
3. By wrapping this string with BASH's math operation like this`$(( "${arr[@]/%/ +} 0"))`, it will return the sum instead

**This could be used for other math operations.**

1. For subtracting just use `-` instead
2. For multiplication use `*` and `1` instead of `0`

**Can be used with logic operators too.**

1. BOOL AND EXAMPLE - check if all items are true (1)

   `arr=(1 0 1)`

   `if [[ $((${arr[@]/%/ &} 1)) -eq 1 ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi`

   This will print: no
2. BOOL OR EXAMPLE - check if any item is true (1)

   `arr=(1 0 0)`

   `if [[ $((${arr[@]/%/ |} 0)) -eq 1 ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi`

   This will print: yes